# Get trigger query using query analyzer

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a server in which there is no SSMS installation, and only query analyzer is available. And all I need to do is find the trigger information (basically trying to find out what that trigger does).

I tried using object explorer in query analyzer, to use "Alter To->New window" command. But that command failed saying "Use SSMS to alter the query".

Is there a way, I can write a simple sql query, that gives me the trigger information?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Found it.

```
sp_helptext 'TriggerName'
```

worked like a charm.